# Compare items of a list sequentially with another one then use one by one in VPython application

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, vpython

I have grid of objects in Vpython created by this code:

```
iX = [(x - pointW // 2) * sclFact for x in range(pointW)]
iY = [(x - pointH // 2) * sclFact for x in range(pointH)]
iYr = iY[::-1]
xy = list(itertools.product(iX,iYr,))
ixyz = np.array(list(itertools.product(iX,iYr,[-0.0])))
for element in ixyz:
        cube = box(pos = element,
               size=( .1, .1, .1 ),)
```

ixyz list print will look like this:

```
[[-0.5  0.  -0. ]
 [-0.5 -0.5 -0. ]
 [ 0.   0.  -0. ]
 [ 0.  -0.5 -0. ]
 [ 0.5  0.  -0. ]
 [ 0.5 -0.5 -0. ]]
```

I have other list that the z value changes sometime depand on certain input and its always updated, it wll look like this

```
[[-0.5        0.        -0.       ]
 [-0.5       -0.5       -0.       ]
 [ 0.         0.        -0.       ]
 [ 0.        -0.5       -0.       ]
 [ 0.5        0.        -2.3570226]
 [ 0.5       -0.5       -0.       ]]
```

I want to move the objects based on the new list, i tried different veriation but it did not work, it always look at the last item in the second list

```
while True:
  .... some code here (the one getting the new list)
  ...
  ...
  # then I added this:
      for obj in scene.objects: 
        if isinstance(obj, box):
            for i in xyz: # xyz is the new list
                if obj.pos != i:
                   obj.pos = i
```

this variation will make all the boxes be one box and move based on the last position in the list

what I am doing wrong or is there another way to do that ?
or should I change the whole process of creating the objects and move them?
I am really new in VPython and python itself.

**Edit**
I fixed both lists to be better presented like this

```
[(-0.5,0.0,-0.0),(-0.5,-0.5,-0.0),...(0.5,-0.5,-0.0)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeatedly setting the position to each element in the updated positions list:

```
box.pos = 1
box.pos = 2
box.pos = 3
```

You need to set the position one time; so compute an index:

```
i = 0
for obj....
    if isinstance  ...
         obj.pos = xyz [i]
         i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work (with some problem I think). I tried to fix the list to be better presented like the edit above then it works. in the beginning, I did not understand your answer until I start to learn a bit about indexing and also after I fix my list.